# Mocking out multiple database calls using pd.read_sql

Tags: python, sql, mocking

I have a function which uses `pd.read_sql` to make two SQL queries directly from Python, as per the below:

```
def get_sql_queries():
   source_data_query = """
        SELECT
              cf."fund" as 'Fund'
            , cf."Symbol"
   FROM
            sql_table
   """

   transactions = pd.read_sql(
        sql=source_data_query,
        con=DEFAULT_CONNECTION,
    )

   other_source_data_query = """
        SELECT
              cf."fund" as 'Fund'
            , cf."Symbol"
   FROM
            other_sql_table
   """
   marks = pd.read_sql(
        sql=other_source_data_query,
        con=DEFAULT_CONNECTION,
    )
   returns transactions,marks
```

This works fine when I'm calling from the database.

I would now like to mock out these database calls for testing purposes, such that when `source_data_query` is run, instead of calling the database, it reads in a test dataframe. Similarly for `other_source_data_query`.

Update: editing as per Aaron's suggestion  below:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
import pandas as pd
from functions import get_transaction_data


class GetSQLQueriesTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('pd.read_sql')
    def test_get_sql_queries(self, mock_read_sql):
        transaction_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Fund', 'Symbol'], data=[['Fund 1', 'Symbol 1']])
        mark_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Fund', 'Symbol'], data=[['Fund 2', 'Symbol 2']])

        mock_read_sql.side_effect = (transaction_data, mark_data)  # If the order is fixed

        output = get_transaction_data.get_transactions_between_two_dates()
        self.assertEqual(output, (transaction_data, mark_data))
```

I'm getting the following error:

`FAILED tests/unit_tests/functions/test.py::GetSQLQueriesTest::test_get_sql_queries - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pd'`

I definitely have pandas installed on my environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) to mock the return value of `pd.read_sql` based on `sql`.

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import pandas as pd

from mymodule import get_sql_queries


class GetSQLQueriesTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('pandas.read_sql')  # Or @mock.patch('mymodule.pd.read_sql')
    def test_get_sql_queries(self, mock_read_sql):
        transaction_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Fund', 'Symbol'], data=[['Fund 1', 'Symbol 1']])
        mark_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Fund', 'Symbol'], data=[['Fund 2', 'Symbol 2']])

        # mock_read_sql.side_effect = (transaction_data, mark_data)  # If the order is fixed
        mock_read_sql.side_effect = lambda sql, con: (
            transaction_data if ' sql_table' in sql else
            mark_data if 'other_sql_table' in sql else
            None
        )

        output = get_sql_queries()
        self.assertEqual(output, (transaction_data, mark_data))
```

Comment: For those who come here in future, I believe using @mock.patch('mymodule.pd.read_sql') as @aaron put in code comment is all that is needed to fix the op's exception from being unable to find module named 'pd'

Comment: Hello, I have tried copied and pasted your code but get the following error message: `AttributeError: 'PandasMock' object has no attribute 'read_sql'`. Why?

Comment: @CodePope What is `PandasMock`? Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then [Ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score -2):

If your goal is to not read in the entire table but just a sample for testing, you would want to add `LIMIT [#ofrows]` to the end of your query where [#ofrows] is however many rows you want for your test run.

you can also get the rows in a random order by using `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT [#ofrows]`

If this wasn't your question you need to provide more clarification as to what you're looking for (see the comments under your post). I would also suggest cleaning up your code in your question as it looks like you're closing "" is immediately after `other_source_data_query =`

Comment: This isn't generally what you'd want to do in a test because you don't usually want your test infra connecting directly to the database.